# Adding Text inside a Shape

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a custom WPF control MyLine that should represent or not some text in its middle.

```
public class MyLine : Shape
{   
    public double X1, Y1, X2, Y2;
    public bool IsTextDisplayed;
    public string Caption;

    protected override System.Windows.Media.Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get
        {
            var geometryGroup = new GeometryGroup();

            if (IsTextDisplayed)
            {
                // calculate text point
                var midPoint = new Point((X1 + X2) / 2.0, (Y1 + Y2) / 2.0);
                // add a TextBlock with the Caption text in that point
                // ???
            }

            // Add line
            geometryGroup.Children.Add(new LineGeometry(
                new Point(X1, Y1), new Point(X2, Y2)));

            return geometryGroup;

        }
    }
}
```

How should I add the a TextBlock (or Label) here?

I tried to add a `FormattedText` inside, but this is NOK, because it draws the text with the line fat brush and is impossible to read something.

EDIT

## Adding a visual Child

```
public MyLine() : base()
{
    textBlock = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock();
    textBlock.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    this.AddVisualChild(textBlock);
}

protected override System.Windows.Media.Geometry DefiningGeometry
{
    get
    {
    ...

if (IsTextDisplayed)
{
    var midPoint = new Point((X1 + X2) / 2.0, (Y1 + Y2) / 2.0);
    string text = "some custom text";

    Canvas.SetLeft(textBlock, midPoint.X);
    Canvas.SetBottom(textBlock, midPoint.Y);

    textBlock.Text = text;
    this.textBlock.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;    
}
else 
{
    this.textBlock.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
}
```

I don't see any label... :"/

EDIT2

## Adding Adorner

```
public MyLine() : base()
{
    this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MyLine_Loaded);
}

void MyLine_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AdornerLayer aLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(this);
    if (aLayer != null)
        aLayer.Add(new TextAdorner(this));        
}

class TextAdorner : Adorner
{
    public TextAdorner(UIElement adornedElement) : base(adornedElement) 
    { }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        MyLine segment = (this.AdornedElement as MyLine);            
        if (segment != null && segment.IsLabelUsed)
        {
            Rect segmentBounds = new Rect(segment.DesiredSize);

            FormattedText ft = new FormattedText(
                "654 m", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture,
                System.Windows.FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                new Typeface("Arial"), 12, Brushes.White);

            drawingContext.DrawText(ft, segmentBounds.BottomRight);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, apparently the code never enters in the OnRender adorner method...

Comment: I hope your Canvas backgroundcolor wasn't white ...

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the text displayed in the same brush as the line, you probably don't want to use a `Shape` as the base class, as the `Geometry` returned from `DefiningGeometry` is rendered in one brush.  If you really want to use a `Shape` as the base class, you probably want to add the text as a visual child rather than add it to the existing `Geometry`.

If you aren't going to be using a lot of these, and can afford a slightly heavy-weight container, I'd suggest simply creating a `UserControl` based control that contains this `Shape` you created, *and* a text element like `TextBox` on a `Canvas` (for absolute positioning).   Again, this is not going to be a great solution if you have hundreds or thousands of these, but if you only have tens of them, it is probably the easiest and quickest solution.

Comment: I already have a working logic with this Shape, mainly, line moving etc. I will search some about visual Child... Just need something to display(or not) a text info near the line it's all.

Comment: If you are going to use the visual child method, you need more than AddVisualChild - oddly enough, that method does not actually add a child, it just sets up the parent/child relationship.  You also would need to override `VisualChildCount`, `GetVisualChild` to actually have the item as a child,  and `ArrangeOverride` to position the element.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an adorner to draw the text on top of the line.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746703.aspx

Comment: added this variant too, but not working as I wrote it, see my edit 2

Comment: You can't do that in the constructor. OnLoaded/OnApply template is where you should AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(this)

Comment: Fixed this, now, apparently the code never enters in the OnRender adorner method... (see the edit)

Comment: I *think* 'OnLoaded' is called after the visual tree has been rendered which is why OnRender is not called. If you move the line it *should* be called. I think OnApplyTemplate is the correct place to add the adorner.